# Serialize is not implemented for PgRange<DateTime<Utc>>

Tags: rust, serde, rust-sqlx

I would like to be able to serialize a struct containing `PgRange<DateTime<Utc>>` however, `#[derive(Serialize)]`  fails for `struct Reservation` with the error:

```
pub timespan: PgRange<DateTime<Utc>>,
^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `PgRange<chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>>`
```

As a workaround, I am splitting the timespan field into two fields which works for serialization, but makes SQL more involved.

The data scheme is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE reservation (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    timespan TSTZRANGE
);

INSERT INTO reservation(timespan) VALUES
    (TSTZRANGE(now() + INTERVAL '0 hour', now() + INTERVAL '1 hour')),
    (TSTZRANGE(now() + INTERVAL '2 hour', now() + INTERVAL '3 hour'));
```

and my working code example :

```
/*
[dependencies]
chrono = { version = "0.4", features = ["serde"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
sqlx = { version = "0.5", features = ["runtime-tokio-native-tls" , "postgres", "chrono"] }
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
*/

use chrono::prelude::*;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use sqlx::FromRow;
use sqlx::postgres::types::PgRange;
use sqlx::postgres::PgPoolOptions;

#[derive(FromRow, Debug)]
pub struct Reservation {
    pub id: i32,
    pub timespan: PgRange<DateTime<Utc>>,
}

#[derive(FromRow, Serialize, Debug)]
pub struct ReservationWorkaroud {
    pub id: i32,
    pub start: DateTime<Utc>,
    pub end: DateTime<Utc>,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), sqlx::Error> {

    let pool = PgPoolOptions::new()
        .max_connections(2)
        .connect(&"postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost")
        .await?;


    // Ideally, I would like my struct to mirror db table as close as possible while being able to serialize/deserialize to/from Json
    let select_query = sqlx::query_as::<_, Reservation>("SELECT id, timespan FROM reservation");
    let reservations: Vec<Reservation> = select_query.fetch_all(&pool).await?;
    dbg!("{:?}", reservations);


    // With the workaroud struct, I am able to serialize it however, sql queries start to get complex especially for inserting:
    let select_query = sqlx::query_as::<_, ReservationWorkaroud>("SELECT id, lower(timespan) AS start, upper(timespan) AS end  FROM reservation");
    let reservations: Vec<ReservationWorkaroud> = select_query.fetch_all(&pool).await?;
    dbg!("{:?}", reservations);

    Ok(())
}
```

How can I make `struct Reservation` serializable ?

## Update

Based on @Caesar's answer, I went with the following approach:

```rust
#[derive(FromRow, Serialize,Debug)]
pub struct Reservation {
    pub id: i32,
    #[serde(serialize_with = "serialize_range", flatten)]
    pub timespan: PgRange<DateTime<Utc>>,
}

fn serialize_range<S, T>(range: &PgRange<T>, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: serde::Serializer,
    T: Serialize,
{
    let PgRange { start, end } = range;
    std::ops::Range { start, end }.serialize(serializer)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to go on about this.

1. My favourite serde trick, use the [container attribute](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#into) `#[serde(into = "ReservationWorkaround")]` on `struct Reservation` and add an `impl Into<ReservationWorkaround> for Reservation {}`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72483890/how-to-rename-start-and-end-range-values-with-serde/72484362#72484362) for an example of using the attribute.
2. Use a custom serialization function

```rust
#[derive(FromRow, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct Reservation {
    pub id: i32,
    #[serde(serialize_with = "serialize_range", flatten)]
    pub timespan: PgRange<DateTime<Utc>>,
}

fn serialize_range<S, T>(range: &PgRange<T>, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
where
    S: serde::Serializer,
    T: Serialize,
{
    // You probably also want to convert start and end
    // from Bound<DateTime<Utc>> to something else here.
    // It is common to define a new struct like
    #[derive(Serialize)] struct I64Range { start: i64, end: i64 }
    // right here in this function
    let PgRange { start, end } = range;
    std::ops::Range { start, end }.serialize(serializer)
}
```

3. In theory, this is a prime use-case for ["remote derive"](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html), but you'd have to come up with a separate solution for converting the `Bound<DateTime<Utc>>`. Maybe the `serde_with` crate can help, but I'm not sure.

```
#[derive(FromRow, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct Reservation {
    pub id: i32,
    #[serde(with = "PgRangeRemote", flatten)]
    pub timespan: PgRange<DateTime<Utc>>,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(remote = "PgRange")]
struct PgRangeRemote<T> {
    start: std::ops::Bound<T>,
    end: std::ops::Bound<T>,
}
```